# Why is my function returning a negative value?

Tags: prolog

So I drew a simple function in prolog that counts how many of a variable are in a matrix.

And it goes like this :

```
:-use_module(library(lists)).
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

countOccurrences([],Y,0).
countOccurrences([X|T], Y, Z):-
    countOccur(X, Y, N),
    Acc #=N + Z,
    countOccurrences(T, Y, Acc).    


countOccur([],X,0).
countOccur([X|T],X,Y):- countOccur(T,X,Z), Y is 1+Z.
countOccur([X1|T],X,Z):- X1\=X,countOccur(T,X,Z).
```

countOccur seems to be working fine and returns the right value. The problem is countOccurences is returning the right absolute value but negative. I Just dont seem to understand why that is happening.

Can someone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An input of `[[a,a,a,a]]` looking for `a` does countOccurrences of `a` in `[]` and sets `Acc = 0` and then countOccur of `a` in `[a,a,a,a]` sets `N=4` then `Acc #= N + Z` becomes `0 #= 4 + Z` and so the result must be `Z = -4`.

Comment: so I should not have the first clause ? @TessellatingHeckler

Comment: @pattyport I think just fixing up the equation to be adding to the TailCount instead of subtracting from it. (and maybe rename all the variables so it's clearer what's happening)